# Has it been proven that all positive even numbers > 2 are either the sum of two primes or the difference between two primes?

Tags: number-theory, goldbachs-conjecture

If a Maillet number is a positive even integer that can be expressed as the difference between two primes and a Goldbach number is a positive even integer that can be expressed as the sum of two primes, the conjecture (theorem?) is that every positive even integer is either a Goldbach number or a Maillet number. Does anyone know if this has been proven, or if one implies the other?

Comment: In fact, the conjecture is that every even number greater than $2$ is both. My guess is that even the conjecture that every even number is at least of one of the types is unknwon, but I might be wrong.

Comment: If a number is both Maillet and Goldbach,it implies that the higher prime used to show it's Maillet, is the sum of 3 primes.